# Excel - Function used within range critera

Tags: microsoft-excel

While defining a range criteria, eg.
=SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, [criteria]);

I've found it is possible to do math operations on the criteria range.

Eg.
=SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, "/2>"&C1)

But have hit a wall where I need to use MOD. It appears however, that criteria can only reference the target cell with the left hand side of an operator. I can't find a way to pass that value *into* a function.

What I need is something like:
=SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, MOD(#, 5)==0)

Where # is the evaluating cell from B:B.

Are there any solutions here?

Comment: Would you not need the double quotes still? `=SUMSIF(A:A, B:B, "MOD(C1,5)==0")`

Comment: The "math operation" is not math at all. It produces a text. Also, the double `&&` will be rejected by Excel.  Can you post an example where that actually works? A screenshot of your data and the formula? And the formula is SumIFS, not SumSIF.

Comment: Thanks teylyn fixed up those issues.
@Aganju your solution there works using the C1 reference. I don't want to reference an individual cell though, I wish to reference the cell being evaluated (from B:B).

Comment: I'd use `SUMPRODUCT` instead.  And I'd also limit the ranges to less than whole-column ranges for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `SUMIF`, however there are a couple of workarounds using `SUM` as [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) or [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function):

- `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A17*(MOD(B2:B17,5)=0))`
- `{=SUM(A2:A17*(MOD(B2:B17,5)=0))}`
- `{=SUM(IF(MOD(B2:B17,5)=0,A2:A17))}`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using another column, then in C1 put :

```
=MOD(B1,5)
```

and drag downwards, then use :

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,"="&0)
```

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: The issue was the number of operations I needed to do was arbitrary, and adjustable in another sheet. SUMPRODUCT worked wonders.